# sending arraylist of list to ajax via json object

Tags: java, json, ajax, hibernate, spring-mvc

"employee" which has EMPID, EMPAGE, ADDRESS, SALARY, EMPNAME, department_id (foreign key refrences to table "department") and "department" table which has department_id, name .. in the department class i made this

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "department")
private List<Employee> employees;
```

in controller.java

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/indexDep")
public @ResponseBody void doPostListDep(HttpServletResponse response) throws 
 JSONException, IOException {
    departmentService.listDepartment(response);
}
```

in departmentService.java

```
public List<Department> listDepartment() {
    return departmentDao.listDepartment();
}
public void listDepartment(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, 
JSONException {
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    List lst = new ArrayList();

         //here listDepartment() returns an list of departments and in each  
         //department returns arraylist of employees ... i want to put this 
          //in json object to be sent .. so how to make this ??


    obj.put("MyListDep", lst);
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    out.write(obj.toString());
    out.close();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code will create an JSONArray with all employees in it:

```
 JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
    for (Department d : listDepartments()) {
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        for (Employee e : d.getEmployees()) {
            obj.put("EMPID", e.getEmpId());
            obj.put("EMPAGE", e.getEmpAge());
            obj.put("ADDRESS", e.getAddress());
            [...]
        }
        array.put(obj);
    }
```

Then you have to send the JSONArray through the `PrintWriter` like:

```
out.write(array.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to make a response object representing the structure of wanted json output and replace list with an array which would be serialized without any effort